# font-css display problem same code on one domain works, on the other it doesn't

Tags: google, css, fonts

font-css display problem
same code on one domain works, on the other it doesn't.

Font Family: 'JOST'

old site run [www.link-motors.it](http://www.link-motors.it)

new site not run [www.linkmotors.it](http://www.linkmotors.it)

who can help me understand? the order of the css is the same.

Comment: Can you ask this in such a way that it doesn't require links to your sites?  Can you instead include the relevant code snippets from your sites that demonstrate the problem?